# Can anyone explain why concatenating many FirstAsync will block completion of parents observables?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, observable, reactive

I'm working with Reactive and I was testing concatenation.
Unfortunately I wasn't able to understand something.
Can anyone explain why only last onCompleted: is being invoked?
I'm really confused about it.
Aren't all FirstAsync supposed to complete once they emit First element?

Simple code example:

```
Observable
.FirstAsync()
.Do(_ =>
    {
                        
    }, onCompleted: () =>
    {
        //Not Invoked               
    })
.FirstAsync()
.Do(_ =>
    {
                        
    }, onCompleted: () =>
    {
        //Properly Invoked       
    });
```

Comment: Please add code as text, rather than as an image

Comment: There's no need of code, unless you're unfamiliar with Reactive

Comment: If Imgur goes down for whatever reason (like Facebook did earlier this week) then the question will lose important context. Please add any text based information as text, not images.

Comment: Changed image to code as requested.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this behavior is quite logical I think.

You're effectively creating a new observable from a source one by doing `source.FirstAsync().FirstAsync()`, and then I suppose that you're subscribing to the new observable.  You'd expect it to return its one value and complete, and it does.  However, there's no reason why the observables it's derived from should complete: you haven't subscribed to them.  There are two observables it's derived from: the original source, and source.FirstAsync().

If source has multiple finite values it would be surprising if it did return all values and complete, since our derived observable is only concerned with the first one.  source.FirstAsync() not completing even though it's returned its one value was probably a design decision to ensure consistency.

I hope that's clear enough - I originally tried to answer with a code example but it was even more confusing.